# Jquery, activate script if hashtag on end of URL matches a class name

Tags: jquery, html

Hey folks. I am using a little bit of jQuery to do a live sort of my portfolio when various categories are selected. Basically, the script matches the content of an `<li>` tag on click (my menu) with the class names of other `<li>` tags elsewhere on the page. The result is the portfolio items match the nav clicked will show and hide the rest. A live sort. However, i want to add the ability to add a permalink to activate the jquery to sort by a hashtag at the end.. for example: `work.html#category1` would automatically set the script to hide everything but category one. My script and basic page setup is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#worknavwrap p a').click(function() {
            $(this).css('outline','none');
            $('ul#worknavwrap .current').removeClass('current');
            $(this).parent().addClass('current');

            var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','_');

            if(filterVal == 'all') {
                $('ul#portfolio li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
            } else {

                $('ul#portfolio li').each(function() {
                    if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                        $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
                    } else {
                        $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
                    }
                });
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
    <ul id="worknavwrap">
      <li><a href="#category1">Category 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#category2">Category 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#category3">Category 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="portfolio">
      <li class="category1">Item 1</li>
      <li class="category1">Item 2</li>
      <li class="category2">Item 3</li>
      <li class="category1">Item 4</li>
      <li class="category3">Item 5</li>
      <li class="category3">Item 6</li>
      <li class="category2">Item 7</li>
      <li class="category1">Item 8</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    $('#worknavwrap a[href=' + window.location.hash + ']').click();
}
```

It will find the `<a>` element that has the `href` attribute matching the hash, and trigger its `.click()` handler.

Even better would be to provide ID attributes for the `<a>` elements like:

```
<ul id="worknavwrap">
    <li><a id="category1" href="#category1">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="category2" href="#category2">Category 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="category3" href="#category3">Category 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

So then you could just do:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    $(window.location.hash).click();
}
```

---

By the way, for your code to match your HTML, you need:

```
$('#worknavwrap li a').click(function() {...
```

instead of:

```
$('#worknavwrap p a').click(function() {...
```

and also:

```
var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','');
```

instead of:

```
var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','_');
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you good sir! I went with the ID method and this worked perfectly. As far as the selectors, they are correct for my original HTMl file but not my snippet I created for this question, whoops. 

Any guesses on why the hash tag is not automatically appending to the URL when each nav item is clicked?

Comment: @liquilife - Probably because of your `return false;` statement at the end of the handler. This prevents the default behavior of the `<a>` element. If you want the default behavior, then you should remove that line.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Everything works perfectly now. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want an insane number of features along with the ability to do what you are looking at I suggest having a delicious BBQ.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/