# How to use local storage to use the addeclass after reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got this script to add to some "li"'s the class "activeyo" when someone clicks it.The links realod the same page , but after the page is reloaded the added class is gone.
I readed this: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054274/remembering-jquery-tab-position-after-page-reloads) and this [Remembering jQuery tab position after page reloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054274/remembering-jquery-tab-position-after-page-reloads)

But i cant understand how to properly use the local storage so i can css properly the li's even after the reload.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#alpha_ul li a ').click(function() {
$('#alpha_ul li a ').removeClass("activeyo");
$(this).addClass("activeyo");
});               
});
```

Tried code:

```
function yo(alpha) {
$('#alpha_ul li a ').removeClass("activeyo");
alpha.addClass("activeyo");

}          
$("#alpha_ul li a").click(function () {
            if (localStorage) localStorage['alpha'] = $(this).closest('li').index();
            yo($(this));
        });      

});
```

The above code does exactly what the first block of code does. after refresh the class is removed.

Comment: Have you even tried it?

Comment: did you try using local storage

Comment: tried this:
 $("a #alpha_ul").click(function () {
            if (localStorage) localStorage['#alpha_ul'] = $(this).closest('li').index();
            activate($(this));
        });

Comment: Its pretty straight-forward. Save something with localStorage.yourVariableName = 'yourValue'; and check if value is set with if(typeof localStorage.yourVariableName !== 'undefined')

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close with your example, the thing you forgot to do is to set the class from the local storage on page load:

```
function yo(alpha) {
    $('#alpha_ul li a ').removeClass("activeyo");
    alpha.addClass("activeyo");
}          

$("#alpha_ul li a").click(function () {
            if (localStorage) localStorage['alpha'] = $(this).closest('li').index();
            yo($(this));
        });      
});

// this is what you need
if (localStorage && localStorage.alpha) {
    yo( $("#alpha_ul li").eq(localStorage.alpha) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.someProp = 'azaza'; // you can add someting to it
localStorage.removeItem('someProp'); // and you can remove something.
```

And that's it. Not sure how do CSS classes relate to the question.
localStorage is global.
localStorage's state is saved through page reloads. So basically if you do

```
localStorage.someProp = 'azaza';
```

and then reload the page you will still have an access to that data by

```
var someValue = localStorage.someProp;
```

Then you can do whatever you want with that value.